# How to create Php Timepicker in 12 hrs format

Tags: php, timepicker

I have used php timepicker in my project and it is 24 hrs format but in new requirement I need to implement this  only 12 hrs format because I have to check time in AM PM format to compare with passed variable value. so what is the process to create in 12 hrs format

```
    <?php 
      $time = strtotime('10:00');

      $end_time = strtotime('20:00');
      $end_time = date("h:i a",$end_time);

        echo '<select>';
        while($time <= $end_time){
            $optionvalue = date("H:i",$time);
            echo '<option value="'.$optionvalue 
              .'">'.$optionvalue.'</option>';
            $time = strtotime('+15 minutes',$time);
        }
        echo '</select>';

    ?>
```

Comment: and your question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `date('h:i a')` to get meridiem  `am`,`pm`

```
$end_time = strtotime('20:00');
$optionvalue = date("h:i a",$end_time);
echo $optionvalue;
```

[Like Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f67816fe1ed13cbee77b146ed6ff7f6065c131f)

Comment: [Check with your code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/404b83921dceaa1089b69aaeb2fb5aed503fbc3a)

Comment: I have updated in question can you please tell me what  mistake I did

Comment: Is above given output is same as you want ?

Comment: remove `$end_time = date("h:i a",$end_time);` and update inside your while loop `$optionvalue = date("h:i a",$time);`

Answer (score 0):

```
/* start and end times converted to DateTime objects */
$start=new DateTime( date( DATE_ATOM, strtotime('10am') ) );
$end=new DateTime( date( DATE_ATOM, strtotime('8pm') ) );
$interval=new DateInterval('PT15M');

/* ensure the initial time is part of the output */
$start->sub( $interval );
$slots=array();

while( $start->add( $interval ) <= $end )$slots[]=$start->format('H:ia');
printf('<select name="times"><option>%s</select>', implode( '<option>', $slots ) );
```

```js
document.querySelector('select[name="times"]').onchange=(e)=>{
alert( e.target.value )
}
```

```html
<select name="times">
 <option>10:00am
 <option>10:15am
 <option>10:30am
 <option>10:45am
 <option>11:00am
 <option>11:15am
 <option>11:30am
 <option>11:45am
 <option>12:00pm
 <option>12:15pm
 <option>12:30pm
 <option>12:45pm
 <option>13:00pm
 <option>13:15pm
 <option>13:30pm
 <option>13:45pm
 <option>14:00pm
 <option>14:15pm
 <option>14:30pm
 <option>14:45pm
 <option>15:00pm
 <option>15:15pm
 <option>15:30pm
 <option>15:45pm
 <option>16:00pm
 <option>16:15pm
 <option>16:30pm
 <option>16:45pm
 <option>17:00pm
 <option>17:15pm
 <option>17:30pm
 <option>17:45pm
 <option>18:00pm
 <option>18:15pm
 <option>18:30pm
 <option>18:45pm
 <option>19:00pm
 <option>19:15pm
 <option>19:30pm
 <option>19:45pm
 <option>20:00pm
</select>
```